# Api Adwords Exeption

Tags: php, google-adwords

Подскажите пожалуйста, Пытаюсь скачать отчет формирую запрос согласно документации вот отсюда [ссылка на пример из библиотеки](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201708/Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReportWithSelector.php)

Вот то как я формирую:

```
$selector = new Selector();
    $selector->setFields([
        SelectorFields::EXTERNAL_CUSTOMER_ID,
        SelectorFields::ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME,
        SelectorFields::DATE,
        SelectorFields::CLICKS,
        SelectorFields::COST,
        SelectorFields::SEARCH_BUDGET_LOST_IMPRESSION_SHARE,
        SelectorFields::CONTENT_BUDGET_LOST_IMPRESSION_SHARE,
        $date_range,
    ]);

    $report_definition = new ReportDefinition($selector);
    $report_definition->setReportName(self::_get_report_name($customer_id));
    $report_definition->setDateRangeType(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::CUSTOM_DATE);
    $report_definition->setReportType(ReportDefinitionReportType::ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);
    $report_definition->setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat::XML);

    $report_downloader = new ReportDownloader($adwords_session_user);
    $report_settings_override = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())
                                ->includeZeroImpressions(true)
                                ->build();

    $report_download_result = $report_downloader->downloadReport($report_definition, $report_settings_override);
```

в результате получаю:

> Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201708\cm\ApiException [ 0 ]: Details: [fieldPath: ; trigger: Invalid ReportDefinition Xml: cvc-type.3.1.2: Element 'fields' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children].; errorString: ReportDownloadError.INVALID_REPORT_DEFINITION_XML]

Может кто сталкивался буду благодарен.

Comment: Вопрос решен, невнимательность.

Comment: $selector->setFields([
            SelectorFields::EXTERNAL_CUSTOMER_ID,
            SelectorFields::ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME,
            SelectorFields::DATE,
            SelectorFields::CLICKS,
            SelectorFields::COST,
            SelectorFields::SEARCH_BUDGET_LOST_IMPRESSION_SHARE,
            SelectorFields::CONTENT_BUDGET_LOST_IMPRESSION_SHARE,
        ]);
        $selector->setDateRange($date_range);